# Linux Mint: lower screen brightness on low battery

Tags: debian, ubuntu, linux-mint, power-management, battery

I'd like to make screen brightness lower on low battery. There's no such options in power settings. Alternatively, I may set the system to shut down in such situation, but that's undesired. Is there any kind of script or bash command that I could use to set lower screen brightness on low battery?

Comment: Which Desktop Environment do you use?

Comment: Cinnamon desktop.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

and give this a try

```
#!/bin/bash

lowBatLevel=25 #battery percent considered low
desiredBrightness=25 #brightness level to lower to ( 0 to 100 )
batLevel=`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage | awk '{print $2}'  | sed 's/.$//'`
curBrightness=`xbacklight -get`

if    [ $curBrightness -gt $desiredBrightness ]  && [ $batLevel -le $lowBatLevel ]  ; then #change 25 to your desired battery % 
xbacklight -set $desiredBrightness
fi
```

I'm not on a linux machine so I have not tested, let me know if you have any errors